# Angular app routeProvider confused in app mounted on sup path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

My single page app is not mounted on the root, so the path to the app is something like `http://…/sub/`. I took care of the base by adding this to the HTML file:

```
<base href="/sub/"/>
```

My routingProvider is set up the way you would expect it to be:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider
  .when("/", { })
  .when("/foo/", { })
  .when("/bar/", { })
```

which is fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9, but on IE8 it fails. In order to make it work, I had to add this to make sure it initializes properly:

```
if (!history.pushState && !window.location.hash) {
    window.location.replace("/sub/#!/");
}
```

Why is that required? Is there another way to get it working in IE8 without resorting to these kind of hacks? (I am on angular 1.2.0.rc.3)

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten my apps to work on IE8+ (and IE7 with varied results), by following the AngularJS IE Compatibility guide: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: I know about that document, but it doesn't say anything about routing.